# client.guilds.get is not a function DISCORD.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

For some odd reason when I try to check if a member is in a guild it throws error

`Uncaught TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function`

Here is a section of my code.

```
//IDS TO BAN
 USER_ID = '860926166956769280 // test account'   //863609914291388467
  USER_ID2 = '863929485845594152' 
  USER_ID3 = '863572599221256203' 
  GUILD = '863564803892576276' // guild to ban members in
  let guildToCheck = client.guilds.get(GUILD), // line it gets stuck on
  server = msg.guild 
  // Check if forbidden users exist.
if (guildToCheck.member.fetch(USER_ID)) {
    server.members.ban(USER_ID)
  }
  if (guildToCheck.member.fetch(USER_ID2)) {
    server.members.ban(USER_ID2)
  }
  if (guildToCheck.member.fetch(USER_ID3)) {
    server.members.ban(USER_ID3)
  }
```

I am using the newest version of Node.js and discord.js.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of DJS v12, you have to go through the `cache` to get a user/channel/guild or use `.fetch()` to get the user from the API, but be warned the latter returns a Promise.

Basically, as long as the guild is already cached, just do `client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD)` and that should solve your error.

Comment: now it throws guildToCheck.member.fetch is not a function

Comment: `member` should be `members`

Comment: Glad I could help